# When does django's values() values_list() get evaluated?

Tags: django, database

Django docs specify when queryset gets evaluated.

When does ValuesListQuerySet, ValuesQuerySet evaluated? (when does it hit the DB?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It acts the same as any normal `QuerySet`, just its output is transformed directly from model instances to dictionaries/tuples respectively before being passed on to you, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: oh really? does that mean, I can pass MyClass.objects.filter(a=a).select_related().values_list('foreign_key_field', flat=True) to a paginator to get paginated result of foreign key field objects? in one db hit?

Comment: you should be yes, it's just a normal QuerySet with processed output for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it is a QuerySet:

> Returns a `QuerySet` that returns dictionaries, rather than model
> instances, when used as an iterable.

[In addition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

**You can evaluate a QuerySet in the following ways:**

1. `Iteration`: A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first time you iterate over it.
2. `Slicing`: As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.
3. `Pickling/Caching`: See the following section for details of what is involved when pickling QuerySets. The important thing for the purposes of this section is that the results are read from the database.
4. `repr()`: A QuerySet is evaluated when you call repr() on it. This is for convenience in the Python interactive interpreter, so you can immediately see your results when using the API interactively.
5. `len()`: A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you might expect, returns the length of the result list.
6. `list()`: Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it.
7. `bool()`: Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, such as using bool(), or, and or an if statement, will cause the query to be executed. If there is at least one result, the QuerySet is True, otherwise False.