# Most efficient way to create a snapshot of a django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I’m new to Django, and I need to clean up all existing objects meeting a certain set of criteria that were previously created by an importer before the importer re-runs.

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this. Currently I'm getting the existing objects before importing the new objects and updating them with a boolean `to_be_deleted=True`:

```
Thing.objects.filter(source=importer).update(to_be_deleted=True)
import_new_things(source=importer)
Thing.objects.filter(to_be_deleted=True).delete()
```

But do I really need to run update on that entire queryset? Is there a way to just save a snapshot of the queryset to a variable and then delete those after the importer finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a "snapshot" of the queryset you could just get a list of the IDs.

```
# Get all the objects IDs
current_object_ids = list(Thing.objects.filter(source=importer).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Then you could call your function, and if it suceeds you could delete your other objects.

```
try:
    import_new_things(source=importer)
except: 
    # do something
else:
    # Run your delete
    Thing.objects.filter(id__in=current_object_ids).delete()
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, but when I tried this suggestion,     `Thing.objects.filter(id__in=current_object_ids)` returns every Thing object.

Comment: oh, i think it just needs to be `current_object_ids = list(Thing.objects.filter(source=importer).values_list('id', flat=True))`?

Comment: Ah yes, you will need to convert it to a list in order to evaluate the queryset. See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254561/1689262